# Adding notes to an iteration or release in Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: tfs

My team and internal business customers often ask the start/end dates for sprints and the projected release date. Is there a way to attach a note to an iteration in TFS so that these dates can be published and/or queried?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following links which describe how to set start and end dates to your sprints and be able to track these dates. Also, check out the new Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 1.0 process templates. It may have the ability to add notes or more information to your iterations since it has a sprint work item type. TFS 2012 has the type of functionality you mentioned as well.

[Make Agile Work for You in TFS 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205635.aspx)

[Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 1.0](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ac03e3-df99-4776-be39-1917cbfc5d8e/)